# How to use For loops and While loops to repeat code block

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, processing

I need the make the 2nd if statement (when a button is pressed) repeat the command 5 times using a for loop, then a while loop for the 3rd if statement

The while and for loops are the things Ive tried but I have not gotten the code to work. It only draws one dot at a random location.

```
    if (mouseX >= BUTTONX && mouseX <= BUTTONX+BUTTONWIDTH && mouseY >= BUTTONY && mouseY <= BUTTONY+BUTTONHEIGHT) {
        //if click on button, choose random position
        x = (int)random(width);
        y = (int)random(height);
    } else {
        if (mouseX >= BUTTONX && mouseX <= BUTTONX+BUTTONWIDTH && mouseY >= BUTTONY2 && mouseY <= BUTTONY2+BUTTONHEIGHT) {
            for(int a = 0; a <= 5; a++){
                x = (int)random(width);
                y = (int)random(height);
            }
        } else {
            if (mouseX >= BUTTONX && mouseX <= BUTTONX+BUTTONWIDTH && mouseY >= BUTTONY3 && mouseY <= BUTTONY3+BUTTONHEIGHT) {
                int i = 0;
                while(i <= 5){
                    x = (int)random(width);
                    y = (int)random(height);
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                //if click off button, place dot at mouse location
                x = mouseX;
                y = mouseY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing Logging statements or breakpoints to see if it's hitting the for/while conditions at all? The structure of your loops looks fine (although they do the exact same thing instantly several times and will appear to only do one thing when executed instead of 5 things)

Comment: My instructor asked me to do the same thing but with two different loops. Wouldnt the x and y be different every time because its being randomly generated? @user1538301

Comment: To continue with @user1538301, you are computing several values for x and y but you are only going to use the final (5th) values since there is nothing in the loop to use them.

Comment: Oh, right, you are using a random number gen function. If it is truly a pseudo-random number generator, yes it will likely be different each time. However nothing is done with x and y when the value is set so you'll only be able to observe one of these loop iterations.

Comment: @fedup beat me to it haha

Comment: Thank you @fedup Turns out I was only drawing the dot once when I needed it to be inside the loop.

Comment: @NineOfDiamonds Noah, don't forget to upvote the answer and check it as accepted - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing several values for x and y but you are only going to use the final (5th) values since there is nothing in the loop to use them